# Filling out cells based on another cell in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, conditional-formatting

I am trying to fill out cells in Google sheets based on another cell. That is, I have drop down list in column `J` and based on what I choose in that column, I need cells in column `K` to fill with a specific number. I tried `conditional formatting`, but that works for colours only, not values. I tried `IF` function, but this doesn´t work either:

[image]

Anyone has any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use in empty column in K2 cell:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(J2:J; 
 {"Cyklistické bundy"\ "2642"; 
  "Dámske bundy"\      "1763"; 
  "Pánske bundy"\      "1739"}; 2; 0)))
```